# Show that $\int |f |d \mu < \infty$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f $ be measurable and suppose we have a sequence $\{s _n \} $ of simple functions such that $s _n \to f $ a.e. and such that $\int |s _n - s _m |d \mu \to 0 $  as $n,m \to \infty $

Define $\int f d \mu = \lim \int s _n d \mu$, where each $\int |s _n| d \mu < \infty $

I want to show that $\int |f |d \mu < \infty$, that is that the above conditions imply that $f $ is integrable.

---

Obviously $\int f d \mu $ exists, from the second assumption above, but I don't thiks this is suficient for $|f |$ to be integrable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have access to the fact $|\int f d\mu| \leq \int |f| d\mu$?

Comment: Yes I can prove that, using this definition

Comment: Oh, sorry, I meant for any function.

Comment: Yes, it is still true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clear that the absolute value of a simple function is simple; $|\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i \mathbb{1}_{A_i}| = \sum_{i=1}^k |\alpha_i| \mathbb{1}_{A_i}$. Therefore, $\{\hat{s}_n \equiv |s_n|\}$ is also a sequence of simple functions.  The absolute value is a continuous function, so we know that $\hat{s}_n \rightarrow |f|$ where $s_n \rightarrow f$, i.e., almost everywhere. And because $||s_n(x)| - |s_m(x)|| \leq |s_n(x)-s_m(x)|$ for all $x$, we have that $\int |\hat{s}_n - \hat{s}_m|d\mu \rightarrow 0$. By the same argument as for the $s_n$, we see that $\int\hat{s}_n$ is a Cauchy sequence. Therefore, we know $\int |f| d\mu = \lim\int\hat{s}_n d\mu$ exists and is finite.

Comment: But this says that $\int f d \mu $ exists, but $\int |f |d \mu \ge |\int f d \mu |$, and so?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. I'll edit.

Comment: No, I haven't defined the integral as that. I only assume the two conditions above. Though I know that what you write is the common definition.

Comment: If you haven't defined the Lebesgue integral of a general signed function that way, then how have you defined it?

Comment: Oh, I get it now! You're constructing the Lebesgue integral from scratch. I'll fix my answer again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort Zach!
@Zach